# Erro de parâmetro em mysqli_query (não aceita parâmetro de conexão)

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde pessoal

Estou com o erro: Warning: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /var/www/html/crudgenerico/classes/Conexao.class.php on line 59

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/crudgenerico/classes/Conexao.class.php on line 59

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/html/crudgenerico/classes/Conexao.class.php on line 59

```
public $host      = "localhost";
public $user     = "root";
public $password = "xxxxxxxx";
public $db       = "crud";
public $dataset  = NULL;
public $linhasAfetadas = -1;

public function __construct() {
    $this->conecta();
}

public function __destruct() {

}

public function conecta() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Erro de conexão (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    } 
}

public function inserir($objeto) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $objeto->tabela . " (";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($objeto->campos_valores); $i++) {
        $sql .= key($objeto->campos_valores);

        if($i < (count($objeto->campos_valores)-1)) {
            $sql .= ", ";
        } else {
            $sql .= ") ";
        }
        next($objeto->campos_valores);
    }
    reset($objeto->campos_valores);
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($objeto->campos_valores); $i++) {
        $sql .= is_numeric($objeto->campos_valores[key($objeto->campos_valores)]) ?
            $objeto->campos_valores[key($objeto->campos_valores)] :
            "'" . $objeto->campos_valores[key($objeto->campos_valores)] . "'";

        if($i < (count($objeto->campos_valores)-1)) {
            $sql .= ", ";
        } else {
            $sql .= ") ";
        }
        next($objeto->campos_valores);
    }

    echo $sql;
    return $this->executaSql($sql);
}

public function executaSql($sql = NULL) {

        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

}

Comment: Faltou passar a conexão para o `mysqli_query()` ele sempre é o primeiro argumento.

Comment: A sintaxe é `$query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql)`, mais detalhes na postagem linkada no fechamento.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma e ele deu o seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in /var/www/html/crudgenerico/classes/Conexao.class.php on line 59

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/crudgenerico/classes/Conexao.class.php on line 59

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/html/crudgenerico/classes/Conexao.class.php on line 59

Comment: Provavelmente você não passou a variável pro seu método, certo? O site é um jeito legal de tirar duvidas de programação, mas já não é tão adequado como "debugger remoto". Basicamente o erro diz que $mysql é nulo, ou seja, você não passou esse parâmetro na sua função (e nem usou um membro da classe no lugar dele).

Comment: Ok, vou tentar ver onde está o erro.

Comment: O problema é `$mysqli`(a conexão) no método `conecta()`, ela é uma váriavel local ou seja quando `concta()` terminar de excutar ela não vai mais existir. A solução que recomendo é tornar `$mysqli` um membro da classe (como $host, $user etc ...) e nas chamadas das funções `mysqli_` fazer da seguinte forma: `mysqli_query($this->mysqli, $sql)`

Comment: Marcelo a solução do @rray é bem adequada, e deve ser simples de vc implementar, mas se tiver dificuldade, deixe comment aqui. Basicamente vc vai usar por exemplo um `public $mysqli` no começo do código, e no lugar dos `$mysqli` existentes, trocar pelo membro `$this->mysqli`.

Comment: PS: ta faltando a conexão aqui tb: `or die( mysqli_error($this->mysqli) );`